# Google Spreadsheet onOpen() + 15

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

im trying to tweak this code to center the cell with todays date to the left of the screen, not the right. 
the solution right now is to put i+25 in the following code:

```
sheet.setActiveRange(range.offset(4,i+25,1,1));
```

but this obviously also selects the wrong cell.. is there a way to select "i+25" to move the screen, then run the same command without "+25" to actually select the correct cell?

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("6:6");   // get all 2nd row
  var values = range.getValues();
  var day = 24*3600*1000;  
  var now = Date.now();  
  var ssdate; 
  for (var i = 0; i < values[0].length; i++) {
    try {
      ssdate = values[0][i].getTime();
    }
    catch(e) {
    }
    if (ssdate && ssdate <= now && now < ssdate + day) {
      sheet.setActiveRange(range.offset(4,i+25,1,1));
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you get an answer to this question? I would like to understand how "onOpen()" works. Thanks